# Stripe 500 internal server error on multiple ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, stripe-payments

I have an application that calls functions in stripe SDK library using ajax.

The first call for charging a customer goes **fine without any problem**.

**Serverside Code for Charge Customer:**

```
<?php
require_once 'stripe/init.php';

// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form

$token = $_POST["token"];
// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array("amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd", "source" => $token, "description" => "Example charge"));

    echo json_encode(array("msg" => "success"));

    exit ;
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    echo json_encode(array("msg" => $e -> getMessage()));
    exit ;
}
```

The second call for creating a new customer gives **500 internal server error**.

**Serverside code for Create Customer:**

```
<?php
require_once 'stripe/init.php';

// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST["token"];
// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
    // add customer
    $email = "example@yahoo.com";
    \Stripe\Customer::create(array("description" => "Customer for " . $email, "source" => $token // obtained with Stripe.js
    ));

    echo json_encode(array("msg" => "success"));
    exit ;
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    echo json_encode(array("msg" => $e -> getMessage()));
    exit ;
}
```

**Here is what I have tried:**

I tried to run the ajax calls individually (one by one) and they both work fine, but the second ajax call always fails when I try to make multiple ajax calls sequentially (one after the another).

I also tried to swap the order of these calls, i.e I tried to call the add customer first and then charge customer as a second call, in this case the customer is added successfully but no matter what order, the second call will always fail and gives a 500 error.

Therefore I think my server side code is correct for both functions "Charge::create" and "Customer::create" but I somehow need to reset something after first ajax call so the second ajax call goes successful aswell.

**Clientside Code**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : 'sp/stripeProcess.php',
    method : "POST",
    data : {
        token : token
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    cache : false,
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.msg == "success") {

            jQuery.ajax({
                url : 'sp/createCustomer.php',
                method : "POST",
                data : {
                    token : token
                },
                dataType : 'json',
                cache : false,
                error : function(jqxhr, textstatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqxhr.status);
                },
                success : function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.msg == "success") {
                        console.log('customer added');
                    } else {
                        jQuery(".payment-errors").text(response.msg);
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            jQuery(".payment-errors").text(response.msg);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with the client side? could you provide the js code?

Comment: @aleksv you can have a look at the clientside code , i have updated the question

Comment: this is probably out of a function or a method. Could you log the token variable and see if it changes after several requests?

Comment: @aleksv I just logged the token variable and it is the same after first ajax call and does not change

Comment: Set the $token = "your token" and then call the page directly in your browser via typing in the url (without ajax). The real error should then be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the issue was that according to the stripe API, the token can only be used once, so in my case this was the solution:

- Use the token once to create a new customer which returns a unique customer ID.
- Make a second ajax call (to charge the customer) by passing the customer ID returned from the first call instead of the token.